# After ssh/rsync to a remote destination, how can the destination machine can know about the new file as soon as the transfer finishes?

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp

I am doing ssh/rsync to a remote server. I want the file to then be transfered by the server to another remote machine (I can't transfer directly). For this, the server should know that it has received a new file as soon as the transfer finishes.

So how the server can know about the new file the earliest?

Comment: why can't you transfer "directly"? Do you know about, for example, ProxyCommand? Covered [here](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html), [here](http://www.statusq.org/archives/2008/07/03/1916/), and [here](http://www.undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20070925181947), or just google around for "[ProxyCommand](https://www.google.com/search?q=ProxyCommand)".

Answer (score 0):

You could use eg. inotify under Linux and have a shell script notified when a new file is created in the directory (have a look at inotify-tools). You could however also check the existance of the file periodically, eg. every second, to find out when it is created (as far as I know, rsync uses temporary filenames for transfers before renaming the file to its final name).